# Create a duplicate copy of Linked list in O(n) time

Tags: c#, c++, c, algorithm

A link list is given with two pointer, 1st is pointing to next node and another is random pointer. Random pointer is pointing to any node of LinkedList. Write a complete program to create a copy of Linked List(c,c++,c#), without changing original list and in O(n).

I was asked this question in one of the interviews and I could not figure out the solution.
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first pointer is pointing to which node?  The "next node" doesn't make much sense from the context that I'm reading.

Comment: Am I missing something?  Why would you not just traverse the list exactly once using the pointer to the next node and copy the list that way?

Comment: I suspect the aim of the interview question was to prompt the candidate to ask questions back to the interviewer, such as the purpose of the pointers - because otherwise the question seems too simple for an interview (unless it was a phone-screening interview).

Comment: I think the point of the question is how to deal with the random pointer.  It's easy to copy a linked list (with just a next node pointer) in order n.  I assume that the copy must also have its own random pointers.  Whether these can be randomized independently or whether these must have the same mappings as the original list would be a good question to ask the interviewer.

Comment: @mawicks Most likely the intention is that you must copy the random pointers. If you can randomize them independently, then this question is ridiculously simple, since you could just traverse the list linearly and copy the fixed pointers and randomize the random pointers. Copying the random pointers is the challenge...

Comment: EDIT NOTE: I backed out a question edit as we have to assume verbatim text in this "interview" question.

Comment: "Random" pointer in the context of the question means it can point to any node on the list, not just the next node. The question is to create an exact duplicate of the original list, with it's random pointers set to the corresponding nodes on the copy. The problem can easily be solved by using an associative structure like a hashmap or dictionary. It becomes more of a challenge when you iterate and ask the solution be implemented in constant space.

Answer (score 17):

Copying a normal linked list in linear time is obviously trivial. The only part that makes this interesting is the "random" pointer. Presumably by "random" you really mean that it points to another randomly chosen node in the same linked list. Presumably, the intent is that the copy of the linked list re-create exactly the same structure -- i.e., the 'next' pointers create a linear list, and the other pointers refer to the same relative nodes (e.g., if the random pointer in the first node of the original list pointed to the fifth node in the original list, then the random pointer in the duplicate list would also point to the fifth node of the duplicate list.

Doing this in N<sup>2</sup> time is fairly easy. First duplicate the list normally, ignoring the random pointer. Then walk through the original list one node at a time, and for each node walk through the list again, to find which node of the list the random pointer referred to (i.e., how many nodes you traverse via the `next` pointers to find a `next` pointer holding the same address as the `random` pointer of the current node. Then walk through the duplicate list and reverse that -- find the N<sup>th</sup> node's address, and put that into the current node's random pointer.

The reason this is O(N<sup>2</sup>) is primarily those linear searches for the right nodes. To get O(N), those searches need to be done with constant complexity instead of linear complexity.

The obvious way to do that would be to build a hash table mapping the address of each node in the original list to the position of that node in the list. Then we can build an array holding the addresses of the nodes in the new list.

With those, fixing up the random pointers is pretty easy. First, we walk through the original list via the `next` pointers, duplicating the nodes, and building our new list connected via the `next` pointers, but leaving the random pointers alone. As we do that, we insert the address and position of each node into the hash table, and the address of each node in the new list into our array.

When we're done with that, we walk through the old list and new list in lock-step. For each node in the old list, we look at the address in that node's random pointer. We look up the position associated with that address in our hash table, then get the address of the node in the new list at that position, and put it into the random pointer of the current node of the new list. Then we advance to the next node in both the old and new lists.

When we're done, we throw away/destroy both the hash table and the array, since our new list now duplicates the structure of the old one, and we don't need the extra data any more.

Comment: Good point, without further attention you can't just copy the 1st node because it points to a node that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: +1 For understanding that when the OP wrote "A link list is given with two pointer ...", what was meant was "A linked list with nodes containing two pointers ...".

Comment: Perfect answer. With this you only need to traverse twice, instead of O(n^2). +1

Answer (score 8):

**Overview of the approach**
We won't try to create a new linked list right from the word go. Duplicate the items in the original linked list first, then split the list into 2 identical lists.

**The details**
**Step 1** : Run through the linked list using the next pointers and create a duplicate of each node.

```
original :: A -> B -> C -> D -> E ->null

updated :: A -> A' -> B -> B' -> C -> C' -> D -> D' ->E -> E' -> null
```

This can be easily done in a single loop.

**Step 2** : Traverse the list again, and fix the random pointers like this

```
Node *current= start;
Node *newListNode, *random;
while (current!= null) {
    // If current node has a random pointer say current = A, A.random = D;
    if ( (*current)->random != null ) {
        // newListNode will point to A'
        newListNode = (*current)->next;
        random = (*current)->random;
        random = (*random)->next;
        // Make A' point to D's next, which is D'
        (*newListNode)->random = random;
    }
    // Here A'.random = D'
    // Current goes to the next node in the original list => B , and not A'
    current= (*newListNode)->next;
}
```

**Step 3** :: Split the list into 2 lists. You just need to fix the next pointers here.

```
Original :: A -> A' -> B -> B' -> C -> C' -> D -> D' ->E -> E' -> null
New :: A -> B -> C -> D -> E ->null
       A' -> B' -> C' -> D' -> E' ->null

Node *start1 = head;
Node *start2 = (*head) ->next      // Please check the boundary conditions yourself,
                                   // I'm assuming that input was a valid list
Node *next, *traverse = start2;
while (traverse != null) {
    next = (*traverse)->next;
    if (next == null) {
        (*traverse)->next = null;
        break;
    }
    (*traverse)->next = (*next)->next;
    traverse = next;
}
```

This way, you've created a copy of the original list in O(n) time. You traverse the list 3 times, which still is order of n.

Answer (score 7):

Clarifying edit:

*The following works only if the "random" pointers are unique, as BowieOwens pointed out.*
I'm leaving the answer just for the general idea, but please don't upvote as it's most definitely **wrong**.

---

If I'm not entirely mistaken, you can do this without using any extra storage.

As you're copying the old list, store the `random` pointer from the old node in the `random` pointer of the new node.
Then, set the `random` pointer of the old node to point at the new node.

This will give you a "zig-zag" structure between the old list and the new list.

Pseudocode:

```
Node* old_node = <whatever>;
Node * new_node = new Node;
new_node->random = old_node->random;
old_node->random = new_node;
```

Once you've copied the old list like that, you start over, but replace the `random` pointers like this, restoring the pointers in the old list while setting the `random` pointers in the new list to the corresponding new nodes:

```
Node* old_random = old_node->random->random; // old list -> new list -> old list
Node* new_random = new_node->random->random; // new list -> old list -> new list
old_node->random = old_random;
new_node->random = new_random;
```

It looks much better on paper, but I'm afraid my ASCII art skills aren't up to it.

This *does* change the original list, but it's restored to the original state.
Whether that's permissible depends on the interview, I guess.

Comment: Does this break down when two nodes in the list both point to the same random node?

Comment: +1: not sure it's exactly an answer to the question, but it is a pretty cool technique anyway.

Comment: @BowieOwens: You mean like in the pictures I posted? I don't believe it does.

Comment: When updating the second pair of nodes the first old node will already have had its random member restored to its original value (which is itself). So new_node->random->random will point into the old list rather than the new list as you assume. So the random pointer in both second new and old nodes will point to the old head node.

Comment: @BowieOwens: You're absolutely right. I had a hunch it was being a bit too clever, and it was.

Answer (score 0):

As you should know, O(n) means linear. As you need a copy of a linear data structure, you will not have problems with it, since you just need to iterate over the nodes of the original list and for each visited node you will create a new node for the new list. I think that the question is not well formulated, because you need to know some aspects to do the job as: this is a circular implementation? What is the "next" node? The next node of a node or the 1st node of the list? How the list ends?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this question is a trick, to test how you answer for strange question, because it's just very simple :

1) Iterate to each node

2) Create new node for other linked list, and copy value.

The cost is always O(n) : because you just iterate to whole linked list for 1 time only !!!

Or, you have understand something wrong on his question.

Comment: There's a random pointer too for every node. In one pass you cannot create an exact copy (the value of the random pointers in the duplicate list, should be the same as the random pointers in the original list).

Comment: @DownVoter please explain for me why you downvote. Are there any problems ?

Comment: @hqt Presumably because it's assuming that the data is just data when it's actually an absolute reference to an item of the linked list that should be converted to an absolute reference to the new item of the linked list.